# foreach duplicating first var consecutively

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to generate query conditions based on an array from a form and this is how I'm doing it:

```
// will this suffice against sql injection?
$filter_type = isset( $_POST['type'] ) ? filter_input( INPUT_POST , 'type', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT , FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY ) : NULL;

$type_cond = '';
if ($filter_type != NULL) {
    foreach ($filter_type as $type=>$value) {
        if ($type === 0) {
            // need to add (int) before $value?
            $type_cond = "AND t2.type = " . $value;
        } else {
            $type_cond .= $type_cond . " OR t2.type = " . $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Output with one array index:

```
AND t2.type = 1
```

Output with two array indexes:

```
AND t2.type = 1AND t2.type = 1 OR t2.type = 2
```

Output with three array indexes:

```
AND t2.type = 1AND t2.type = 1 OR t2.type = 2AND t2.type = 1AND t2.type = 1 OR t2.type = 2 OR t2.type = 3
```

Why is repeating that consecutively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this:

```
$a .= $b;
```

causes `$b` to be added to the current content of `$a`. Therefore, if you write this:

```
$a .= $a . $b
```

will add the content of `$a` to `$a` (thus the repeating), and then add the content of `$b`.

So you need to replace this:

```
$type_cond .= $type_cond . " OR t2.type = " . $value;
```

with this:

```
$type_cond .= " OR t2.type = " . $value;
```

Comment: Some links: [viper](http://www.viper-7.com/vwMol5) and [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) ^^